# IE and Edge sending encoded URL to the server

Tags: javascript, date, decodeuricomponent

I am trying to send some parameters from a booking form to an online booking company's website. The idea is to get a quick redirection for the visitor to the website with a date and a date plus one day (in JavaScript) for the booking as a starting point.

Everything works fine in Chrome & Firefox. In IE and Edge though the tail end date is sent with encoding thus:

https://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/?startdate=2018-02-28&adults1=1&children1=0&enddate=2018-3-01

Which works fine from *Chrome* etc. Once this has been generated in *IE* or *Edge* though it does not work. It is sending this to the server:

https://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/?startdate=2018-02-28&adults1=1&children1=0&enddate=%E2%80%8E2018-%E2%80%8E03%E2%80%8E-%E2%80%8E01%E2%80%8E

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('#book-room').click(function () {
    var term = jQuery('#fromdate').val();
    var dateAr = term.split('/');
    var newFromDate = dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[0].slice(-2);
    // Plus One Date:
    var myDate = new Date(newFromDate);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate(term) + 1);
    var plusOneDate = myDate.toLocaleString( 'en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month : 'numeric', day : '2-digit' } );
    var newDay = plusOneDate.replace(/\//g, '-');
    var dateAr2 = newDay.split('-');
    var newPlusOneDate = dateAr2[2] + '-' + dateAr2[1] + '-' + dateAr2[0].substr(0); 
    window.open(decodeURIComponent("https://xxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/?startdate=" + newFromDate + "&adults1=" + newAdults + "&children1=" + newChildren + "&enddate=" + newPlusOneDate), "_blank");
  });
})
```

The `newPlusOneDate` is the variable that is causing all the trouble.
It should be in the format **2018-3-01** which is required at the other end. The form date works fine everywhere.

The only way I could get the date + one day (`newPlusOneDate`) variable to be formatted correctly was using that rather long-winded `toLocaleString()` function and chopping it up. there must be an easier way.

I have tried to use `decodeURIComponent` and `decodeURI` too to rid myself of the encoding but without success.

Any suggestions on how to get the last date string correctly formatted without the encoding would be extremely welcome.

Comment: Why are you doing `decodeURIComponent`? Other than that I don't see anything that could mess with URI encoding. Can you check each step of building the string to find where the URI encoding appears?

Comment: I think you should try to changing the way to build `newPlusOneDate`. It can be `var newPlusOneDate = myDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (myDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + myDate.getDay();`

Comment: doesn't urlencode work? you should url encode each parameter value and concat the whole URL with all parameters, something like http://yourdomain.com/xxxxx?param1=encodeURIComponent(value1)&param2=encodeURIComponent(value2)